# Python program assigning code to random integer, and checking with user input not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, while-loop

```
#test
import subprocess
import time
import random
programClass=[]
code=random.randint(100,1000)
print('This is your secret code! PLEASE WRITE THIS DOWN!')
print(code)
numRafflePeople=0

tester=1
while tester==1:
    code1=input('What is your name, phone number, and email?\n')
    print('code',code1)
    code=code
    if code==code1:
        print('Blah')
        time.sleep(5)
        tester=2
    else:
        print('fail')
        tester=1
```

This program makes a random number, then checks to see if the inputed number is the same as the random number, however when I run the program the program does not seem to be able to identify they are the same.

The random number will be like 303. I will type 303, and the fail message will be printed, can someone please explain the error in my code?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. The while loop is not necessary for the issue here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Its fine, I got the answer I desired, the while loop is necessary for my bigger project, but it seemed to big

Comment: My point is that you should post a smaller example that reproduces the issue. Basically, you're comparing a string to an int

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do in this certain example, thanks though ill remember this for the future! You have been a great help towards asking relevant questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user gives input, code1 becomes a string. code is an integer.

When comparing the two in the boolean, code==code1, it will always be false.

Just change it to:

```
code1=int(input('What is your name, phone number, and email?\n'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert your input to `int`:

```
import time
import random

code = random.randint(100,1000)
print('This is your secret code! PLEASE WRITE THIS DOWN!')
print(code)

tester = 1
while tester == 1:
    code1 = int(input('What is your name, phone number, and email?\n'))
    print('code', code1)
    if code == code1:
        print('Blah')
        time.sleep(5)
        tester = 2
    else:
        print('fail')
        tester = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I could accept both `str` and `int` inputs, is that possible?

Comment: @Ques `input()` **always** returns a `str` in Python3

Comment: Though in this circumstance can I accept both `str` and `int` inputs throughout the same `input('___')` question?

Comment: As @cricket_007 said. You always retrieve a string with user input; depending on your use case, you may have to cast it, or parse it.